# In prayer for sick, can one name count for two people?

Tags: tefilla, names, choleh-sick, kavana-intent, gabbai

On Shabbat morning, the gabbai prays for the sick to be healed and reads out a list of names of sick people, that was provided by the community.

In the case where two sick people have the same name (and mothers' name), must the name be repeated (once for each), or can it be said once for both of them?

Comment: Or maybe the opposite, the heavenly bureau will get confused and no one will get Refuah.

Comment: I vote to say twice, but mentioning their family names.

Comment: @AlBerko Based on Hilchos Gittin, I wouldn’t be surprised if that’s a requirement if two people in the city have the same name, even if one of them isn’t on the list. But what if they have the same family name...and are originally from the same city...

Comment: @DonielF I don't think, 1. It is said in low not to announce it publically 2. we learn from א' נא רפא נא לה that one does not have to mention the name to intend for someone else.  Anyway mentioning names is simply customary and does not have Halochos.

Comment: @AlBerko I wasn’t paskening. I just said I wouldn’t be surprised. In any event, Moshe only got away with that because he said לה and had in mind who that was referring to. You can’t just say “heal” with no intention of an antecedent and expect it to do anything. While I could hear an argument that the Gabbai is just passing along the tefillos of those who submit the names, I’d expect that he would at least need to know that they’re not the same person at a minimum.

Comment: @DonielF Here's for you https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96858/does-a-person-with-did-need-to-be-mentioned-by-both-names

Comment: I highly doubt that works or is even fair to the ill person. Many ill people (or their families) request that a prayer be said for them. They are aware that their name will be included among other names. Why should they be excluded just because someone else has the same name? If you and your co-worker had the same name, would you want one paycheck to cover for both of you? What one can do is not include any names and just say "kol hacholim" (all ill people). It's about as "effective" and in a congregational setting, it's quicker, esp. on a weekday instead of announcing 50 names, individually.